# How can I reproduce this mass-spring effect?

Tags: mass, computational-physics, spring, simulations, software

I am trying to reproduce the multiball object of [this app](https://liine.net/en/downloads/lemur) (you can download it to see by yourself). Press 'e' if you want to emulate the object on your computer (this is a tablet program). Here is [a video as an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ouTLi5SmMuw&t=377s) even if I strongly advise you to download the editor to have a better view.

Basically I have 3 parameters which are (attraction, friction and speed) the mass spring acts on a 2D plan, when touching the screen the ball "rotates" around the contact point, from what I've understood the equilibrium is the contact point of the finger on the screen.

If anyone could explain to me how I could reproduce this effect, I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Just as a friendly suggestion, you are more likely to get people who will read your question if you provide more of an explanation within the question itself, instead of requiring people to follow a link. I think the number of people who will install and run the app is likely to be very small.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately I'm not really good at diagram, this is why I left a video link. The best way to understand how it works is to download the app, I wouldn't be able to describe in proper english the effect I get but I will try my best and improve my post. Just a question, are you going to download the app to have alook ? thanks in advance

Comment: I describe the math and Python implementation of a spring-mass-damper system that goes "boing" [here](http://john.maloney.org/Programming/pythonboing.htm); perhaps it will be of use.

Comment: thanks a lot @Chemomechanics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based purely on watching a few second clip of video, without digging into the internals of the software, it seems plausible that the ball moves on the screen according to the equations of motion for an unforced 2d damped harmonic oscillator. Letting $x$ and $y$ be coordinates of the ball, and $(x_{\rm eq},y_{\rm eq})$ be the position of the equilibrium of the spring (which you said is the position where your finger touches the screen), the equations of motion are
\begin{eqnarray}
m \ddot{x} + \gamma \dot{x} + k (x-x_{\rm eq}) = 0 \\
m \ddot{y} + \gamma \dot{y} + k (y-y_{\rm eq}) = 0 \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $m$ is the mass of the ball, $\gamma$ is a coefficient describing the strength of friction, and $k$ is the spring constant. All three of these parameters should be tunable in the code. The example in the video looks like it was overdamped, meaning that $\gamma^2>4 m k$. ([Hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/oscda.html) has a good descriptions of different regimes of behavior for the damped harmonic oscillator)

One also needs to specify initial conditions. I assume that when you tap the screen, the simulator solves the above equations, with the equilibrium position $(x_{\rm eq}, y_{\rm eq})$ being the position of your finger, and the initial position and velocity being the position and velocity of the ball at the time the screen was tapped.

Finally, the last ingredient one needs are boundary conditions to say what the ball does when it reaches the edge of the screen. I suspect the code uses reflecting boundary conditions, so for example at the moment when the $x$ coordinate hits either the minimum or maximum allowed value of $x$, the velocity in the $x$ direction changes sign.

To actually code this up, in general you can use standard algorithms to integrate the differential equations, such as a [Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods). Or, implementations of those methods in whatever programming language you are using. For this specific problem, which is linear, you can use an analytical solution (explicit formula that gives the motion), for example see [Eq 72 of the notes on Waves and Oscillations by Richard Fitzpatrick](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node10.html#s3.1)
\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& A e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \phi) \\
y(t) &=& B e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \psi) \\
\end{eqnarray}
where $\omega=\sqrt{k/m}$ and where $A, B, \phi, \psi$ are constants chosen to satisfy the initial conditions (namely that the initial position $(x(0), y(0))$ and the initial velocity $(\dot{x}(0),\dot{y}(0))$ match the position and velocity of the ball at the time you touch the screen).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I'll defenitely try what you've written down

Comment: @JSmith You probably want to choose $m, \gamma, k$ so the system is *overdamped*, which will occur if $\gamma^2 > 4 m k$.

Comment: sorry but this is chinese to me I'm really a pity in mathematics

Comment: @JSmith At some point you will need to pick values for $\gamma, m, k$. I recommend choosing them so that $\gamma^2>4mk$ if you want the behavior to be similar to the one in the video.

Comment: oh okay thanks for the advice.

Comment: to be honest I'm struggling on the differential equation part, any idea how I could get to the point? Any already implemented code I could look at. Thanks

Comment: @JSmith Is your problem understanding where the equation comes from or how to solve it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127857/discussion-between-jsmith-and-andrew).