# Trying to find constant of motion formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring, simulations

I have a ball that oscillates around a point.
The ball have an origin and a destination (the point where the screen is touched).
This destination is the equilibrium.
One operator gave me this equation that is supposed to be the motion of a mass attached to a spring

\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& A e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \phi) \\
y(t) &=& B e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \psi) \\
\end{eqnarray}

Only problem is I don't know how to calculate $A, B, \phi, \psi$. The original post was closed and was [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653031/).

I've tried many things without any success I will write another post for this, but for the moment I would like to know how to calculate these constants.

(from what I've understood $\phi, \psi$ should be the phase shift (but I'm not sure)).

Comment: You determine the parameters with the initial conditions. So if $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot{x}(0) = 0$ for instance, you get $A = x_0$ and $\phi = 0$.

Comment: @tomtom1-4 thank you for your comment but I'm not sure to understand. Basically I have one origin and one touched point. I'm trying to get the ball rotate around the touched point. is A supposed to be the equilibrium or the origin? also do you have a formula to calculate phi and psi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ and $B$ are the size of the oscillations in the $x$ and $y$ directions, you could choose these so the image stays near the point, they might need to represent the distance from the origin to where the screen was touched.

Don't worry too much about $\gamma, \psi$ and $ \phi$ set to zero.

$\omega$ sets the speed of oscillation, the bigger it is, the faster is the oscillation.

Try the above to start with, these conditions should make the ball oscillate with the destination as the equilibrium position.  If you wanted a circular motion, try setting one of $\psi$ or $ \phi$ equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (about 1.57).  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will test this

Comment: Ok, it would be interesting if you post back what happens also, you might need to add on a starting co-ordinate to the two formulae you gave e.g. if touched point was (3,2) it might need 3+A... and 2+B...

Comment: Sure I'll do that

Comment: @JSmith Thanks, what happened with it, does it work now?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes it works I've added friction so the ball stops. I only have problem finding the good parameters so I don't have glitches on the screen due to bad frequency. Now on my side this is only a start I have many other problems to solve like the attraction and many more. Many many thanks

Comment: You're welcome, all the best with the rest

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, you basically have two times the same equation, because you describe your 2D-oscillation as two independent 1D-oszillations in each spacial direction. So for this answer, I will only focus on the first equation,
$$
x(t) = A e^{-\gamma t/2} \cos(\omega t - \phi)~,
$$
and the procedure for the second will be exactly analoguous.

Now $x(t)$ is the solution of some differential equation describing a damped harmonic oscillator, which is of the general form
$$
\partial_t^2 x(t) + \alpha \partial_t x(t) + \beta x(t) = 0~.
$$
This is a second order linear, homogeneous, ordinary differential equation, which needs two boundary conditions to determine it's solutions exactly. For example, let's say $x(0) = x_0$ and $\dot x(0) := \partial_t x(0) = v_0$, then we find
$$
A e^{-\gamma \cdot 0 / 2} \cos(\omega \cdot 0 - \phi) = x_0~, \qquad - \frac \gamma 2 A e^{-\gamma \cdot 0/2} \cos(\omega \cdot 0 - \phi) - A \omega e^{-\gamma \cdot 0 / 2} \sin(\omega \cdot 0 - \phi) = v_0~.
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow A \cos(\phi) = x_0~, \qquad - \frac \gamma 2 A\cos(\phi) - A \omega\sin(\phi) = v_0~.
$$
$$
\Rightarrow A = \frac{x_0}{\cos(\phi)}~, \qquad - \frac{\gamma}{2} x_0 - x_0 \omega \tan(\phi) = v_0~.
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \phi = \arctan\left(-\frac{\frac \gamma 2 x_0 + v_0}{x_0 \omega}\right) = \arctan \left( - \frac{\gamma}{2\omega} - \frac{v_0}{x_0\omega} \right)~.
$$

**Remark 1:** It is not important, *which* boundary conditions you choose. I used the position and velocity at time $t = 0$, but you could also use the position at times $t = t_1$ and $t = t_2 \neq t_1$ or whatever else you have given for your problem.

**Remark 2:** The parameters $\phi$ and $\psi$ are indeed the phase shifts at $t=0$. Furthermore, $A,B$ are the amplitudes of the oscillations in the respective direction, $\gamma$ is the damping rate and $\omega$ the frequency. Please note, however, that $\omega$ is *not* the eigenfrequency of the spring that causes the oscillation, because it is influenced by the damping, so $\omega(\gamma)$ as actually a function of the damping rate.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer but unfortunately I'm not able to understand it. Do you have simple terms and equation to explain this? If A is the amplitude shouldn't I add the distance between origin and destination. Also I didn't understood how to calculate phi. (I'm definetely not a mathematician or physicist) thanks in advance

Comment: @JSmith Sorry, I tried to give a conceptional answer, because that is what in my experience is most often requested on this site. From your comments on John Hunter's answer I assume that by now you got what you needed, so I will not try and further elaborate. Feel free to ask again in case that assumption is wrong.

Comment: Yes the other post actually solved my issue. But many thanks for your answer anyway.